# Java - Does setting fields allocates another memory?

Tags: java

I have a code that looks like the code below.

```
public class Controller {
    public void test(){
        Model1 model1 = new Model1();
        Test test = new Test(model1);

    }
}

public class Test {
    private Model1 model1;

    public Test(Model1 model1) {
        this.model1 = model1;//this line
    }

    public Model1 getModel1() {
        return model1;
    }

    public void setModel1(Model1 model1) {
        this.model1 = model1;
    }

}
public class Model1 {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }
    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }
    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }
    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

}
```

I just want to know, how many Model1 is actually created in this code?
Another question is does this line is passed by reference and does passed
by reference is good in memory?

Comment: Simple rule 1: in general, only *new* creates new objects. Simple rule 2: neither assignments nor passing arguments creates a copy/clone/duplicate of an object.

Answer (score 3):

No, assigning to a field does not allocate memory.

Objects are only created when you (directly or indirectly) call a constructor.

> Another question is does this line is passed by reference and does passed
>   by reference is good in memory?

Technically, everything in Java is passed by value.

However, in the case of Objects, this value is a reference to the Object (not a copy of its contents).

So passing an Object around is just the same as passing a `long` around as far as memory layout is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one object in memory, by the line:

```
Model1 model1 = new Model1();
```

And the variable `model1` is a reference to this object.

On the constructor

```
public Test(Model1 model1) {
    this.model1 = model1;//this line
}
```

You will have another reference to the same object in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You have created just one object of class Model. Basically, you create objects only by using the operator `new`.

In java, objects are always passed by value regardless of their type. For non-primitive types (objects), you only have access through reference. So in your case you are passing a reference by value.

Passing objects by reference is good in terms of memory, because you only create another pointer, which takes somewhere between 4-8 bytes.